# Get parent index with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml

```
<ul class="bullets">
  <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I click on the `<a>` element, i'd like to get it's parent `<li>`'s index number.

I'm trying to create a carrousel type function that doesn't need item-n classes on the list items.

```
$(".bullets li a").click(function(){

   var myIndex = $(this).parent().index(this);
   showPic(myIndex);

});
```

Thanks for any help.

TD.

Comment: Will you sometimes have an <li> with no <a>?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
$(".bullets li a").click(function(){

   var myIndex = $(this).parent().prevAll().length;
   showPic(myIndex);

});
```

---

Note: **`prevAll().length`** will give you a zero-based index; the first item will be 0 (zero).

Comment: Kindly note the date of this answer. [James' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306503/get-parent-index-with-jquery/5488252#5488252) is simpler and more up-to-date.

Comment: I find this a lot better than the other answer when you don't have 'this' directly.  You don't go like $('blabla').parent().index($(blabla)).

Answer (score 43):

`$(this).parent().index();`

short and sweet

Correction : this is not short and sweet

from where this comes it should be like:

```
$(".bullets li a").click(function(){
    var myIndex = $(this).parent().index();
    console.log(myIndex);
    showPic(myIndex);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".bullets li a").click(function(){
    var myIndex = $(this).parent().index();
    console.log(myIndex);
    showPic(myIndex);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

How I'd do it

```
$(".bullets li a").click(function()
    {
  var $li = $(this).parent();
  var myIndex = $li.parent().children().index( $li );
  alert( myIndex );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".bullets li a").click(function(){
   var me = $(this);
   var myIndex = $.each($("li", $(this).parent().parent()), function(i, item){
      if(item == me){
      showPic(i);
   });
});
```

Comment: A bit long-winded, don't you think?

Comment: Thank you both very much!
I was looking at the wrong function, stupid .index()

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I created using tables. you can see how I used the selectors. Im sure it could be cleaner, but here you are:

```
    $('.showColumn').live('click',function() {
        var theEl = {{id of the element}};
        var setEl = $('th#' + theEl + '');
        var index = setEl.index(setEl.parentNode);
        $('table tr').each(function() { 
            $('th:eq(' + index + ')',this).show(); 
            $('td:eq(' + index + ')',this).show();
        });
    });
```

cheers.bo