# Get a index number from LI

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get parent index with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306503/get-parent-index-with-jquery)

If I click on `li a` - I want to get a index number of `li`

For example:

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a class="active" href='#'>One</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Two</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have tried the jQuery code, it dont seem to work?

```
$("ul.tabs li a").on("click",function() {
        var li = $(this).prev();
        alert($(li).index(this));
});
```

Comment: This isn't the problem, but you don't need to wrap jQuery objects with `$()`. Eg: `$(li).index(this)` could be `li.index(this)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `.parent()` not `.prev()`

```
var li = $(this).parent();
alert( li.index() );
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hcjGb/1/)

Comment: I tried that, I am getting -1 when I click on href Three.. it should be 2.

Comment: I've added a working fiddle

Comment: `li` is already a jQuery object, you don't need to wrap it in `$()`.

Comment: @ChristianVarga you're right - just copypasted the OP's code, but fixed now

Answer (score 0):

this one worked for me; http://jsfiddle.net/mqdAe/

HTML

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a class="active" href='#'>One</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Two</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Three</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$("ul.tabs li a").on("click",function() {
        var li = $(this).parent();
        alert(li.index());
});
```